# Rxjs throttleTime - do we need to use asObservable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have been using these two (pretty identical methods) of calling throttleTime, but I am unsure if thery are actually identical or not.

```
this.scrollSubject$ = new Subject<Event>();
this.scrollSubscription$ = this.scrollSubject$
                    .asObservable()
                    .throttleTime(400, undefined, { trailing: true })
                    .subscribe(event => this.throttledScrollHandler(event));
```

The same as above, but with `asObservable`

```
this.scrollSubscription$ = this.scrollSubject$
                .throttleTime(400, undefined, { trailing: true})
                .subscribe( event => this.throttledScrollHandler(event));
```

I forgot to add the `asObservable` on my second one, but it behaved in the same way, which was a surprise. Are these two methods the same?

I'm using Observables in Angular, but I don't think this is Angular specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is: yes, if you want to ensure that the subject's `next`, `error` and `complete` methods cannot be called via the composed observable, you should use `asObservable`.

So the two snippets in the question are not the same.

`Subject` implements [`lift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Subject.ts#L46-L50). This means that the observable returned from an operator is a `Subject`. So, unless `asObservable` is called, it will be possible for `next`, `error` or `complete` to be called on the composed observable.

```js
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

const withoutAsObservable = subject
  .do(value => console.log(value));
console.log("withoutAsObservable is a subject:", withoutAsObservable instanceof Rx.Subject);

const withAsObservable = subject
  .asObservable()
  .do(value => console.log(value));
console.log("withAsObservable is a subject:", withAsObservable instanceof Rx.Subject);

subject.subscribe(
  value => console.log("subject value:", value),
  error => console.log("subject error:", error)
);
withoutAsObservable.next("some value");
withoutAsObservable.error(new Error("some error"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

For more information on `lift` see [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/60).

---

Regarding your comment on another answer:

> I can call this.scrollSubscription$['next'](new Event('asdf'));, and throttledScrollHandler() will print out that event

Calling `next` on the `Subscription` calls the `next` method on the `Subscriber` that was created from the `next` function you passed to `subscribe`. It has nothing to so with the subject and is not equivalent to calling the subject's `next` method.

The implementation of `subscribe` [calls `toSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L197) and that subscriber [is returned](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L212).
 [`Subscriber` extends `Subscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Subscriber.ts#L17), but it also has a [`next` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Subscriber.ts#L87-L98). And that's what you are calling.

Comment: Added an explanation for why a `next` method exists on the `Subscription`.